# Port Number for Incoming Apple Push Notifications

Tags: push-notification, push, apple-push-notifications, port-number

What network services, port numbers, outgoing incoming or both, need to be open on a network for an ipod touch to receive Apple Push Notifications?

I know the outgoing port number to set when sending the apns. The only thing is, in my school practically every outgoing (and incoming) port is blocked and as a result APNs do not work. I am sure that if I talked to my network administrator and told him which port to unblock, he would do so. So my question is: What network services, port numbers, outgoing incoming or both, need to be open on a network for an ipod touch to receive Apple Push Notifications?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [Apple's docs](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3576): port 5223.

> If the device is connected over Wi-Fi
>   and is still unable to receive
>   notifications, the Wi-Fi network
>   you're using might have a firewall
>   that is blocking port 5223. This port
>   must be open to TCP traffic for
>   notifications to work.

Comment: Apple also states that you should "open TCP Port 443 (used as a fallback on Wi-fi only, when devices are unable to communicate to APNs on port 5223)".

Answer (score 3):

For APNS to work from within your network you must be able to communicate to 17.0.0.0/8:5223. The TCP connection is made from iOS device out to *.push.apple.com. There is no inbound TCP connections required.