# APNS port number & host name for Push Notification

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, push-notification

If I understand it correctly, Push Notifications are sent to port # 5223. Now, which server port we are talking about here. I am running my application on a device which is on some WiFi network.

I want to know the host name (IP address) of the server on whose port # 5223 Pushes are sent by APNS.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve by knowing IP?

Comment: I am not getting Push Notifications on one WiFi connection whereas it comes on another WiFi.

Comment: You need to open port 5223 on your firewall.

See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1950546/port-number-for-incoming-apple-push-notifications

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple answers your question very clearly [here](http://support.apple.com/en-us/TS4264):

> The APNs servers use load balancing. Your devices will not always
>   connect to the same public IP address for notifications. The entire
>   17.0.0.0/8 address block is assigned to Apple, so it's best to allow this range in your firewall settings.

And to clarify the ports thingy, the devices use port 5223 to communicate to the APNs servers or port 443 as a fallback on Wi-fi only, when devices are unable to communicate to APNs on port 5223.

Comment: Without telling us at least one hostname, how are we supposed to test if the connection is open? "Blindly open the firewall" isn't very good advice.

Comment: @RossPresser See https://stackoverflow.com/a/19806794/1001100 for the host names

Answer (score 2):

They are sent directly to your phone on port 5223, so APNS will send the IP of your phone.  Your phone can have multiple IP addresses if it's on 3G and Wifi at the same time.  So, it's not really possible to answer your question directly.

Comment: Any official documentation? Do you mean Apple will store all the IP address of the devices? doesn't sound making sense, as IP address changes from time to time.

Comment: Sorry, I think I misread your question.  You want to know the IP of the Apple server that is going to send you the push notification?

Comment: My question is : how does Apple locate a specific iPhone, as IP of iPhone changes from time to time? How does Apple route to the device? (maybe I should create a new question, though)

Comment: Presumably the phone checks in with apple's servers on a regular basis.  As far as I know, apple does not publish the details of the implementation.

Comment: if phone polls Apple server regularly, that's a pull mechanism, isn't it?

Comment: Not really.  The phone would be contacting Apple to tell it its device ID and IP address.  Apple would then contact the phone when it has a push notification for it.  It's actually push in both directions if you think about it.

Comment: I see. How about device without real IP ( those within NAT network ) ? Apple definitely doesn't know how to route through, unless a socket channel (or something like that) established...