# Server name of apple for push notification testing in Production

Tags: iphone, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

What is the apple server's/host name for push notification testing of iPhone in production mode?

Comment: did u want to send push notification directly from iPhone device to another iphone device? If it is so then NO, you can not send Push Notifications directly between two devices. Push notifications are sent from a dedicated server that you own or have hosted by somebody else.

Comment: apple push server url is :  "ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195"
You need to check this 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/CommunicatingWIthAPS.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For production:

```
gateway.push.apple.com, port 2195
```

For development:

```
gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com, port 2195
```

Note: Every app generates different pushtokens for production and development mode. Don't send the same one to both.

Source: [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/CommunicatingWIthAPS.html)